# Writing a program to count the letters in a name

Tags: python

> Write a complete Python program that will ask the user to input their name, then the program will output the number of characters in that name, and then count out each of those letters to the end.

When I run the program, I want it to look like this:

```
Please enter your name: Micheal
Your name has 7 characters in it

The 1 letter in  your name is M
The 2 letter in your name is i
The 3 letter in your name is c 
The 4 letter in your name is h
The 5 letter in your name is e
The 6 letter in your name is a 
the 7 letter in your name is l
```

I need the code for this program and also the program should be able to run when you input any name. I already got how to enter a name and use the len function to count how many characters are in the name, but i can't figure out how to do the rest. I am using python version 2.7.6 for windows so I want the code according to this version.

This is what i have:

```
name=raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print

print"Your name has", len(name),"characters in it"
print

for char in name:
    print char
```

Comment: @michealb, what part of the solution is not clear to you?

Comment: take a look at `enumerate` (ie, `help(enumerate)`).

Answer (score 2):

To get the value and index of every element in an iterable, use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate). This built-in function takes each element and its index, putting each as a `tuple` into a `list`.

Demo:

```
>>> for index, char in enumerate(name):
...     print('The {} item in your name is {}'.format(i+1, item))
... 

The 1 item in your name is M
The 2 item in your name is i
The 3 item in your name is c
The 4 item in your name is h
The 5 item in your name is a
The 6 item in your name is e
The 7 item in your name is l
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [the `enumerate` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

`enumerate` takes a single iterable object (like a string) as its argument and returns  an iterator that yields `index, item` tuples. `enumerate("Michael")` would yield `(0, "M"), (1, "i"), (2, "c")` and so on, which seems to be almost exactly what you want (you can pass a `start` value, if you don't want to start at index zero). You can unpack the tuple values right in the loop with `for index, char in enumerate(name, start=1):`.

Another suggestion is to use `str.format` to prepare your output, rather than just chaining together items with commas in your `print` statements. You probably want `"The {} letter in your name is {}".format(index, char)` or something very similar.